# Converting string to Datetime using TryParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime-format

The datetime string value comes as "20170721T114700Z".

How do I convert above string to DateTime using DateTime.TryParseExact ?

How about below code? can someone please correct the issue please?

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
string rawValue = "20170721T114700Z";

if(DateTime.TryParseExact(rawValue , DateTimeFormats.IndexDateTimeFormat, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    //rest of the code...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(rawValue, "yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss'Z'", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    //rest of the code...
}
```

### UPDATE

For 24h format - `"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"`

**[Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4vN2i0)**

Comment: How about using DateTimeFormats Enum?

Comment: @Sameera I'm not familiar with that enum, in which assembly is it?

Comment: @SeM Sorry, It comes form a custom dll

Comment: @Sameera the thing is, that the second argument should be `string` or `string[]`, it can't be enum, so if your code compiles, then `DateTimeFormats.IndexDateTimeFormat` is `string` (or `string[]`).

Comment: this works for 20170726T015300Z (7/26/2017 7:23 AM)
but does not work for 20170726T135300Z (7/26/2017 7:23 PM)

Comment: @Sameera if your strings in 24h format, then use `HH`  instead of `hh`.